# Module not found when using CDK Python Layer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-lambda-layers

I am very new to AWS CDK development.
I am trying to run some simple layer python code in a Lambda.

My directory structure looks like the following:

[image]

The constructs code:

```
# test_api_lambda_stack.py
lambda_layer = aws_lambda.LayerVersion(
    self,
    "lambda-layer",
    code=aws_lambda.AssetCode("./lambda/layer"),
    compatible_runtimes=[Runtime.PYTHON_3_9],
)

lambda_with_layers = aws_lambda.Function(
    self,
    "test-lambda-with-layers",
    runtime=Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
    function_name="test-lambda-with-layers",
    code=aws_lambda.Code.from_asset("./lambda/code"),
    handler="my_lambda_code.handler",
    environment={"NAME": "cdk-lambda-layer"},
    layers=[lambda_layer],
)

...
```

Now, in my layer I simply have this function:

```
# layer/python/logic/logic.py
def add(x: int, y: int):
    return x + y
```

Which I attempt calling from my lambda code:

```
# my_lambda_code.py
from logic import *

def handler(event, context):
    print("SUM worked: " + str(add(1, 2)))
    ...
```

Following deployment and upon running the above, I receive `[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'my_lambda_code': No module named 'logic'`.

How should I import the layer in my lambda, in order to make this work?
Is there a way to navigate the file structure created by this deployment?

Comment: I think the issue here is with how you are importing your code in your LayerVersion. As per example from their documentation, it should be `code=lambda_.Code.from_asset(path.join(__dirname, "lambda-handler")),`. [Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/LayerVersion.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by:

1. Moving the `add` fun to a class (making it a method) - e.g: `SimpleLogic`

```
class SimpleLogic:
  def add(self, x: int, y: int):
      return x + y
```

2. I then moved such class file inside a package (`logic`) in a lib directory structure:

[image]

3. I fixed the import in my lambda:

```
from logic.SimpleLogic import SimpleLogic

def handler(event, context):
    simple_logic = SimpleLogic()
    print("SUM worked: " + str(simple_logic.add(1, 2)))
```